# SF Menu Not Displaying In Wordpress

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, superfish

I have the following superfish menu that i wish to display in my wordpress site:

http://rusticblonde.hostizzo.com/

I have called the js in my functions file as below:-

```
<?php
function my_scripts_method() {
wp_enqueue_script('superfish', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/superfish.js', array('jquery')
);
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method');
?>
<?php
register_nav_menu('main', 'Main navigation menu');
?>
```

I have also called the CSS file in the header:-

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://rusticblonde.hostizzo.com/wp-content/themes/randomtheme/css/superfish.css" />
```

I have just wrapped it in a DIV, however for some reason it is not displaying at all!

```
<div id="menudiv">
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu_class' => 'menu sf-menu' ) ); ?> 
</div>
```

Can anyone assist?
Thanks
Kirsty

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the Super Fish menu :)

In your `header.php`(or alternatively in a separate js file in your theme, called with `wp_enqueue_script()`), add the following code(if it's a separate file, skip the opening and closing `<script>` tags):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function($){
        $(document).ready(function(){ 
            $(".menudiv > div > ul").addClass('sf-menu').superfish();
        });
    })(jQuery)
</script>
```

Also it seems like your `ul` is not getting the `sf-menu` class for some reason - that's why there is a `addClass()` call to the menu before initializing it.

Comment: Hi Nikola, I have the enqueue_script in my functions file already to call the js?

Comment: Yes, but you are only including the SuperFish js. See [this](http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/#examples) link for the example how you are supposed to initialize the plugin itself(including it is not enough) :)